# Finding maximal length value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form `{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [13. 11]}`. I want to find the length of the longest value in the dict. In this case that will be 4. I know how to do this with an array as follows:

```
maxSoFar = 0;
for key in dict.keys():
  if dict[key] > maxSoFar :
    maxSoFar = len(dict[key])
```

My question is, is there a magic one liner to do this?

Comment: With so many answers, can we have a comparison on speed?

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using [`max` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max)

```
max(len(l) for l in dict.values()) # 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
max(map(len, dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
max(dict.values(), key=len)
```

Comment: This will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, not 4.

Comment: This is nice because it will give you the list itself.

Comment: @vaultah I thought that is what the OP wanted - see the question again

Comment: Just did - *I want to find the length of the longest value in the dict*

Comment: The question and the example code are contradictory

Comment: Fixed the code. Doesn't matter so much. I know how to compute the length of the list once I have it :)